# Finding a specific GitLab tag from PHP

Tags: php, git, laravel, gitlab

We have a JIRA instance that our custom PHP app built in Laravel pulls from and for each issue looks to see if a specific branch or tag exists:

```
chdir($path . $repo);
exec("git rev-parse --verify ".$branch, $branch_dump, $return_var);
if ($return_var == 0) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

However, we have migrated all of our git projects to GitLab and that method no longer works, since you need root to get into GitLab's repo data directory.

We looked at GitLab's API and found that we could do this:

```
http://gitlab/api/v3/projects/10/repository/commits/OUR-TAG-HERE?private_token=XXX
```

However this requires us to specify an arbitrary GitLab project ID (10 in this case) and therefore isn't predictable, so we can't programmatically execute the search for each JIRA API return like we did before. This method would work if we could simply search for tags using the project name only, but I can't find a way to do that.

Here's an overlook at the way the app works:

- JIRA contains all issues we want
- Each issue contains several custom fields we use to search our git repos with, generically they are "Repo Name" and "Tag Name"
- Our Laravel app connects to JIRA's api and harvests all issues into an array we use to build a table listing information about each issue
- The two custom fields "Repo Name" and "Tag Name" are matched against our git repositories to determine which of several options to provide the end user (clone tag, create tag if repo exists but no tag exists, or none if neither)

We briefly considered adding another custom field to our JIRA issues which we would fill with GitLab's project ID, but we have hundreds of issues and it is an inelegant solution that really only acts as another potential point of failure, to say nothing of the extra maintenance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found to this issue was to use the API to get the list of projects and use that list to pair name and ID.

For example, this code will output the tag names for all your projects:

```
//Get Projects list via API
$header = array("PRIVATE-TOKEN: <YOUR_TOKEN>");

$ch = curl_init("https://<YOUR_GITLAB_DOMAIN>/api/v3/projects/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//Parse returned list to an array
$projectsArray= json_decode($result, true);

//Loop over the array of projects accessing the list of tags via the API
foreach ($projectsArray as $project) {
  echo $project["name"] . " Tags:<br>";

  $tagURL = "https://<YOUR_GITLAB_DOMAIN>/api/v3/projects/" . $project["id"] . "/repository/tags";
  $ch2 = curl_init($tagURL);
  curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
  curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $result2 = curl_exec($ch2);
  curl_close($ch2);

  $tagsArray= json_decode($result2, true);
  foreach ($tagsArray as $tag) {echo $tag["name"] . "<br>";}
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, we initially implemented this very functionality but saw much slower page loads as a result, so we went with the very simple and dirty trick of simply looking at HTTP response codes, I've posted one of our methods as the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Since arbitrary project IDs are still required by the GitLab API for this functionality we've scrapped the API altogether. Instead we're now simply cURLing HTTP response codes. Here's one of our methods to see if the issue has a tag:

```
public function HasTag($projectName, $nameSpace, $tagName)
{
    $url=$this->gitLabUrl.'/'.$nameSpace.'/'.$projectName.'/tags/'.$tagName;
    $ch = curl_init();                                  // Initiate curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     // Will return the response, if false print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                // Set the url
    curl_exec($ch);                                     // Execute
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here's our method to check for a branch:

```
public function HasBranch($projectName, $nameSpace, $branchName)
{
    $url=$this->gitLabUrl.'/'.$nameSpace.'/'.$projectName.'/tree/'.$branchName;
    $ch = curl_init();                                  // Initiate curl
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);    // Disable SSL verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);     // Will return the response, if false print the response
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                // Set the url
    curl_exec($ch);                                     // Execute
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

As you can see this is pretty simple and hacky, but it works for our implementation because none of the projects being accessed are private (our GitLab instance is purely internal).

Hopefully in the future GitLab will remove the ID requirement from its API.